# Get values from a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

Hey I have this JSONarray and i wonder how to get the values `ProductName`, `description`, and `cost` from the array.

I use the following method to get a value like for example `quantity`:

```
quantitybasket.setText(basket.getString("quantity"));
```

When I try to get `productName` the `logcat` says that `ProductName` does not contain any value.

What do i have to do to get those values?

```
[{"id":4,"quantity":2,"product":{"id":2,"productName":"Audi R8","description":"The best of Audi","cost":1000000.0,"rrp":1500000.0,"product_category":[{"id":2,"category":{"id":1,"categoryname":"Supercars"}},{"id":3,"category":{"id":2,"categoryname":"Sportscars"}}]}}]
```

I save every value in an Android `TextView`

```
TextView productbasket = (TextView) productsListItem
    .findViewById(R.id.product_name_basket);

TextView descriptionbasket = (TextView) productsListItem
    .findViewById(R.id.description_basket);

TextView costbasket = (TextView) productsListItem
    .findViewById(R.id.cost_basket);

TextView quantitybasket = (TextView) productsListItem
    .findViewById(R.id.quantity_basket);
```

Comment: How are you de-serializing the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Google gson` . An excellent Java library to work with JSON.

find it here: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Using `gson` library classes you can do something like this:

```
    String myJson = "[{\"id\":4,\"quantity\":2,\"product\":{\"id\":2,\"productName\":\"Audi R8\",\"description\":\"The best of Audi\",\"cost\":1000000.0,\"rrp\":1500000.0,\"product_category\":[{\"id\":2,\"category\":{\"id\":1,\"categoryname\":\"Supercars\"}},{\"id\":3,\"category\":{\"id\":2,\"categoryname\":\"Sportscars\"}}]}}]";
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(myJson);
    // This is because your json string is an array {}
    JsonArray myJsonAsArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
    // Now inside the json array, you get an object, so get it first from '0' index
    JsonObject mainObject = myJsonAsArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    // Now you have a 'product' JsonObject inside the main object
    // You can directly get it by using String name
    JsonObject productObject = mainObject.getAsJsonObject("product");
    // Once you have 'Product' object, you can get individual elements by following
    String productName = productObject.get("productName").getAsString();
    // This will print out "Audi R8"
    System.out.println(productName);

    //You know how it works. Now get other individual elements of the product object by name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user3476614 As you seem new to StackOverflow, I should guide you that - once you ask a question and you get answer which is right solution then you MUST tick the answer as approved answer, so that others who come back to this question know the accepted right solution, and also that way your question won't be listed in the 'unanswered' questions category. It's important to follow these guidelines to keep this community clean and clear. I hope you understand.